# How to use single Hub(SignalRHub) with multi Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, real-time, signalr-hub, real-time-data

How can I initialize single(SignalR Hub) with multi Form.
For example: when I'm insert new Entry Data from **EntryPage** and sent notify to hub and want to get that notify from **ListingPage**.
Now I don't get that notify when I'm using multiple page because of can't start Hub connection. 

I got the following error message.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:11325/Home/signalr/hubs"
Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
```

When I'm using single page (Entry + Listing) there is no issue.
Where I need to do script reference for multiple page-single hub.
I'm using the following script reference at all of page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Script/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Please see the idea I want to do.==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYfVP.jpg 
Also, How can use ***Multiple Hubs*** with ***Multiple Page*** and ***Single Hub*** with ***Multiple page***?
Please anyone can share?
If you can answer I'm really appreciate it.
Thanks,
     *MinChanSike*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this be the problem?

```
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Change this to:

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```